# Global device memory size limit when using statically alocated memory in cuda

Tags: memory, cuda

I thought the maximal size of  global memory should be only limited by the GPU device no matter it is allocated statically using `__device__ __manged__` or dynamically using `cudaMalloc`.

But I found that if using the `__device__ manged__` way, the maximum array size I can declare is much smaller than the GPU device limit.

The minimal working example is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

#define MX 64
#define MY 64
#define MZ 64

#define NX 64
#define NY 64

#define M (MX * MY * MZ)


__device__ __managed__ float A[NY][NX][M];
__device__ __managed__ float B[NY][NX][M];

__global__ void swapAB()
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for(int j = 0; j < NY; j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
            A[j][i][tid] = B[j][i][tid];
}


int main()
{
    swapAB<<<M/256,256>>>();
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    return 0;
}
```

It uses `64 ^5 * 2 * 4 / 2^30 GB = 8 GB` global memory, and I'll run compile and run it on a Nvidia Telsa K40c GPU which has a 12GB global memory.

Compiler cmd:

```
nvcc test.cu -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
```

Output warning:

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion.
```

When I ran the generated executable, an error says:

```
GPUassert: an illegal memory access was encountered test.cu
```

Surprisingly, if I use the dynamically allocated global memory of the same size (8GB) via the `cudaMalloc` API instead, there is no compiling warning and runtime error.

I'm wondering if there are any special limitation about the allocatable size of static global device memory in CUDA.

Thanks!

PS: OS and CUDA: CentOS 6.5 x64, CUDA-7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would appear to be a limitation of the CUDA runtime API. The root cause is this function (in CUDA 7.5):

```
__cudaRegisterVar(
        void **fatCubinHandle,
        char  *hostVar,
        char  *deviceAddress,
  const char  *deviceName,
        int    ext,
        int    size,
        int    constant,
        int    global
);
```

which only accepts a signed int for the size of any statically declared device variable. This would limit the maximum size to 2^31 (2147483648) bytes. The warning you see is because the CUDA front end is emitting boilerplate code containing calls to `__cudaResgisterVar` like this:

```
__cudaRegisterManagedVariable(__T26, __shadow_var(A,::A), 0, 4294967296, 0, 0);
__cudaRegisterManagedVariable(__T26, __shadow_var(B,::B), 0, 4294967296, 0, 0);
```

It is the 4294967296 which is the source of the problem. The size will overflow the signed integer and cause the API call to blow up. So it seems you are limited to 2Gb per static variable for the moment. I would recommend raising this as a bug with NVIDIA if it is a serious problem for your application.

Comment: You're right, the static memory is limited to 2Gb. I'll try raising this as a bug.  BTW,  the reason I want to use the statically declared multi-dimensional array is that I found them are much more efficient for my multi-dimensional physical modeling code. Using a 1D dynamically allocated array evolves lots of integer operations when addressing data    elements in a 3D stencil.

Comment: I've tried the CUDA 8.0 RC, the bug is still there. :(